# A general question regarding the correct way to implement a dictionary data structure

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

in any dictionary data structure there is an add_to_ds function which receives the data
needed to insert as a parameter.
the question is this:should the add_to_ds get the object it self (type T) and do the memory allocation,or should the add_to_ds get a pointer to object and just insert the pointer (type T*,whoever uses the DS does the memory allocation).

what is the right way do do it,and why ?

Comment: Details please. What language? What does the current implementation look like?

Comment: @Oded I don't know if it really matters but I'm working with C/C++,
and I'm referring to data structures like linked list,binary tree,skip list etc'

Comment: Well, it matters because you are talking about pointers. Not all languages support them, you know.

Comment: you're right (so as said it's C,C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any generally right / wrong way to do it. If you trust the caller not to modify the memory, you're fine storing a pointer. If, however you don't specify this in your interface, you'll have to duplicate the memory.

- If you let them enter pointers, they
  will be responsible with freeing memory, not touching it etc
- If you *don't* trust them, you'll have to free memory, you'll have to return copies to stored items (otherwise if you return your pointer they might free it / alter it)

Comment: @Belgi If you don't want that performance hit, just let clients know they're hosed if they free / modify the data.

Comment: Try to not trust your users/programmers AT ALL. You'll write much better, safer code that way.